# Create user with some restriction in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I am creating user in mongo db who can perform following operation on database :-

- createCollection
- createIndex
- find
- insert
- update

But user can't remove or delete record from database/collection .

I am using following code :-

```
db.addUser({ 
           user:"rwUser", pwd:"password", 
           roles:["readWrite"] 
           })
```

But this user can delete record too . how can i restrict user to delete record from database.

Comment: @Duane13 I want to give all permission only want to restrict to delete record .

Comment: This is not a programming question but about databases adminstration and should have been posted to dba.stackexchange.com[http://dba.stackexchange.com]. That said, it shouldn't have been hard to search for this and read the documentation either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom role with the wanted privileges: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/define-roles/

Connect to your mongo and `db.createRole` with the wanted privileges. You can find the privileges listed here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/. Then just grant the user this role or create a user with this role.

The privileges you want here are:

```
createCollection
createIndex
find
insert
update
```

So for example:

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "foobarRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "exampleDb", collection: "bar" }, actions: [ "createCollection", "createIndex", "find", "insert", "update" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

And grant this to an existing user:

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
  "foobarUser",
  [
    { role: "foobarRole", db: "exampleDb" }
  ]
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you Darin, I have improved my answer. To be honest, I thought this was an easily understood concept, if one just would have searched for it. Thats why I just pointed to the related doc in the first place.

Comment: Per nwarriorch, who attempted to edit this but didn't have the rep to comment: *Note: You cannot run `aggregate() , mapReduce()` or `findAndModify()` with the above set of permissions.*

Comment: Is there a way to create a custom role for all databases and collections without having to explicitly type out every database and collection and modify for any future databases and collections?